# Ember model is gone when I use the renderTemplate hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js, yeoman

I have a single template - editPerson.hbs

```
<form role="form">
    FirstName: {{input type="text" value=model.firstName }} <br/>
    LastName: {{input type="text" value=model.lastName }}
</form>
```

I want to render this template when the user wants to edit an existing person or create a new person. So, I set up routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route("createPerson", { path: "/person/new" });
    this.route("editPerson", { path: "/person/:id"});
    // other routes not show for brevity
});
```

So, I define two routes - one for create and one for edit:

```
App.CreatePersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     renderTemplate: function(){
          this.render("editPerson", { controller: "editPerson" });
     },
     model: function(){
          return {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" };
     }
});

App.EditPersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({     
     model: function(id){
          return {firstName: "John Existing", lastName: "Smith Existing" };
     }
});
```

So, I hard-code the models. I'm concerned about the createPerson route. I'm telling it to render the editPersonTemplate and to use the editPerson controller (which I don't show because I don't think it matters - but I made one, though.)

When I use renderTemplate, I lose the model John Smith, which in turn, won't display on the editTemplate on the web page. Why?

I "fixed" this by creating a separate and identical (to editPerson.hbs) createPerson.hbs, and removing the renderTemplate hook in the CreatePerson. It works as expected, but I find it somewhat troubling to have a separate and identical template for the edit and create cases.

I looked everywhere for how to properly do this, and I found no answers.

Comment: You pass the EditPersonController to the render call, however your controller is likely unloaded because your EditPersonRoute has not entered yet. Anyway, your current example does not make sense to me, why are you loading a model in CreatePersonRoute and passing the EditPersonController to that route.

Comment: To me, creating and editing a person should have only 1 UI (1 template) - so it seems absurd to have to create 2 templates that have identical markup for two "save patient" scenarios. Also, I'm loading a model from the create route because I'm planning to call an external API to load quite a few drop-down selection values (such as gender, race, religion, etc., that I don't want to hard-code on the template).

Comment: Then, it may be solved by CreatePersonRoute.renderTemplate ->    this.render("editPerson", { controller: controller });.            Anyway, I would recommend you to setup a emberjs.jsbin.com in order people can help you easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion - it works! Of course, I had to have the controller parameter for the renderTemplate function. I can't believe this isn't in the Ember guide!

Comment: Some cases are described http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/, I think your problem was only to pass the incorrect controller which was not loaded at this time.